# Angularjs directive isn't selecting the correct option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Question**: How do I select the correct option based on the person's gender.

1) I'm trying to put information in the directive so that i could have multiple selects on a page.. This one will read the gender values.  I put the ng-if on there because the directive was loading before I read which gender the person had.  (there may be a better way to handle this)

```
MarkUP
<label>Gender:</label>
<directive-dropdown ng-if="$ctrl.PersonOC.GENDER"  id="ddlGender" entity-name="GENDER" dd-value="true" selected-value="{{$ctrl.PersonOC.GENDER}}"></directive-dropdown>
```

2)In the directive i read the options from a service.  But I don't know how to select the 'M'.

```
Directive
var dropdownApp = angular.module('dropdownApp', ['core.pvms']);


dropdownApp.directive('directiveDropdown', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        entityName: '@',
        ddValue: '@',
        selectedValue: '@',  
        ngModel: '='
    }
    ,template: '<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.DROP_DOWN_VALUE for option in pvmsOptions track by option.CD">' +   
                '<option value="">-- select one --</option></select>'
    ,replace: true
    ,controller: ['$scope', 'pvmsService', function ($scope, pvmsService) {
        var paramsObj = {};
        paramsObj.entityName = $scope.entityName;
        paramsObj.ddValue = $scope.ddValue;

        $scope.pvmsOptions = pvmsService.query(paramsObj);
        if ($scope.ngModel != '') {
            $scope.ngModel = $scope.selectedValue;
        }
    } ]
    ,link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.ngModel = $scope.selectedValue;
    }
};
});
```

3) You can see in the rendered html that the 1st option is selected, rather than 'Male'

```
Rendered Html
<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.DROP_DOWN_VALUE for option in pvmsOptions track by option.CD" 
ng-if="$ctrl.PersonOC.GENDER" id="ddlGender" entity-name="GENDER" dd-value="true" selected-value="M" 
class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-empty">
<option value="" class="" selected="selected">-- select one --</option>
<option label="FEMALE         " value="F">FEMALE         </option>
<option label="MALE           " value="M">MALE           </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue was that the promise wasn't complete yet... so in the link I added logic to check if the data was present.   After that was successful I looped thru the pvmsOptions and set ngModal to the appropriate one.

```
, controller: ['$scope', 'pvmsService', function ($scope, pvmsService) {
        var paramsObj = {};
        paramsObj.entityName = $scope.entityName;
        paramsObj.ddValue = $scope.ddValue;

        $scope.pvmsOptions = pvmsService.get(paramsObj);

    } ]
            ,link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {                   

                    //put this here to wait until the data has been actually read.
                    $scope.pvmsOptions.$promise.then(function(data) {
                        //console.log(data);

                        //loop thru and select the value from the db.
                        angular.forEach($scope.pvmsOptions, function (s) {
                                if (s.CD == $scope.selectedValue) {
                                $scope.ngModel = s;
                                }});

                    });
              },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `require: 'ngModel'` on your directive to gain access to the [`ngModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).  From there you can use `ngModelController`'s `$setViewValue` and `$commitViewValue` methods.

```
Directive
var dropdownApp = angular.module('dropdownApp', ['core.pvms']);


dropdownApp.directive('directiveDropdown', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        entityName: '@',
        ddValue: '@',
        selectedValue: '@',  
        ngModel: '='
    }
    ,template: '<select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.DROP_DOWN_VALUE for option in pvmsOptions track by option.CD">' +   
                '<option value="">-- select one --</option></select>'
    ,replace: true
    ,require: 'ngModel'
    ,controller: ['$scope', 'pvmsService', function ($scope, pvmsService) {
        var paramsObj = {};
        paramsObj.entityName = $scope.entityName;
        paramsObj.ddValue = $scope.ddValue;

        $scope.pvmsOptions = pvmsService.query(paramsObj);
        if ($scope.ngModel != '') {
            $scope.ModelCtrl.$setViewValue($scope.selectedValue);
            $scope.ModelCtrl.$commitViewValue();
        }
    } ]
    ,link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ModelCtrl) {
        $scope.ModelCtrl = ModelCtrl;
        ModelCtrl.$setViewValue($scope.selectedValue);
        ModelCtrl.$commitViewValue();
    }
};
});
```

Comment: how does ModelCtrl get referenced in the 'controller' section?   Neither of these work.  TypeError: $scope.ngModel.$setViewValue is not a function or ReferenceError: ngModelCtrl is not defined.   ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($scope.selectedValue);
               ngModelCtrl.$commitViewValue();
               //or
               $scope.ngModel.$setViewValue($scope.selectedValue);
               $scope.ngModel.$commitViewValue();

Comment: Ah yes sorry, you need to use the directive's link function to make the *required* ModelCtrl available to the directive's own controller.  The simplest is to expose it on `$scope`.  Another way would be for the directive to require both itself and ngModel, then rig up a `setModelController` function to pass it from link to controller.  I have updated my answer with the first method.